# Isotope sort callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope jquery plugin to sort a number of files in a list by name or date. The isotope function runs perfectly, but I need to run a callback function after the sorting takes place and I can't figure out where to trigger it.

Here is my isotope code so far:

```
function animationFinished() {
    $('#isotope-container a').each(function(index, element) {
        var top = parseInt($(element).css('top')); console.log(top);
    });
}

var $container = $('#isotope-container').isotope({
    getSortData: {
        name: '[title]',
        date: function( itemElem ) { // function
          var date = $( itemElem ).attr('year');
          return parseInt(date);
        }
    }
});
$('#sorting').change( function() {
    //console.log('click');
    var sortByValue = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-sort-by');
    $container.isotope({ sortBy: sortByValue });
});
```

Here is a small example of the html it is sorting

```
<div id="sorts" class="button-group">
  <p>Sort by:
  <select id="sorting">
    <option data-sort-by="name">Name</option>
    <option data-sort-by="date">Date</option>
  </select></p>
</div>

<div id="isotope-container">
<a title="Army Corps of Engineers" year="2009" href="/army-corp-of-engineers-tom-river-rehab-nj-2009/">Army Corp of Engineers</a>
<a year="1999" title="Bolted Steel NSF Tank A6 &amp; A7" href="/bolted-steel-nsf-tank-a6-a7-houston-1999/">Bolted Steel</a>
<a year="1998" title="Brick Manhole Raven 405" href="/brick-manhole-raven-405-charleston-1998/">Brick Manhole</a>
<a year="9999" title="Wetwell Vault Rehab" href="/wetwell-vault-rehab/">Wetwell Vault</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Isotope v2

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/events.html

```
$container.isotope( 'on', 'layoutComplete', function(){ … } ); //only set this up once

$container.isotope({ sortBy: sortByValue });
```

## Isotope v1

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/tests/callbacks.html

```
$container.isotope({ sortBy: sortByValue }, function(){ … });
```

Comment: I did. And I tried exactly what you put and it doesn't work. The sorting happens, but the function is not called.

Comment: Make sure you have at least the last version of isotope.js : http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/jquery.isotope.min.js

Comment: ho, I see, would you be able to use the v1.5.26? Or else we have to find the documentation with the version 2.0.1

Comment: I got something for you here : $container.isotope( 'on', 'layoutComplete', function() {...})